# Way to have a Debian package reinstall when dependency updates?

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging

For [a little something I made](https://github.com/sixtyfive/de_dmg/) (that used to be a word-of-mouth thing only and that's interesting to just a very narrow, and usually non-technical, user base), I'd like to be able to provide a `.deb` file for easier installation.

The something doesn't have any actual files that it needs to install in the system. Instead it needs to add some lines to already existing files (which belong to the `xkb-data` package on Debian-derived distributions). To the best of my knowledge, after searching and asking around, there's no way to put these lines into new, separate files and still have them be picked up by the system, so I wrote a [Rakefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881482/what-is-a-rakefile) to do the installation. That works well but requires the user to interact with a command-line, which doesn't always work so well. Also, whenever `xkb-data` gets updated through the package manager, the rake task needs to be ran again manually, which is cumbersome.

I know about [DpkgPostpone](https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgPostpone) and [DpkgTriggers](https://wiki.debian.org/DpkgTriggers), but none of these seem to be intended or fit for dealing with the above described problem (please do correct me if I'm wrong about that, though!)

Is there any way to have a Debian package *automatically* cause its own reinstall based on the condition that one or all of its dependencies have just been updated? I'm explicitly also interested in a hackish way to do so, [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) be damned.

Comment: It is not clear what was already tried and how can we assist into complementing that. The question is too broad as it is. I would advise seeing our FAQ.

Comment: I googled with various search words, asked on irc.freenode.net#debian (where people said it might be possible, but they don't know how), read the two Wiki pages about Postpone and Triggers that are linked in the question and then ran out of ideas. Hence the question here. Do you have any concrete suggestions as to how it could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reasonable way of going about this is as follows:

- [divert](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg-divert) all the files you modify, so that `dpkg` no longer replaces them, but instead installs them with a different name;
- make your `Rakefile` do its work using the newly-named files instead of the originals, reading the newly-named files and writing the originals;
- install a post-invoke `dpkg` hook in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d` which runs the `Rakefile` after `dpkg` runs.

You could add additional checks, for example only run the `Rakefile` if the checksums of the original files have changed since the last time the modified files were generated, but that might not save much time compared to running the `Rakefile` every time `dpkg` runs, and adds a fair amount of maintenance complexity. (I wrote this assuming that your `Rakefile` behaved like a Makefile, *i.e.* didn’t do anything if its targets were newer that their prerequisites, but I get the impression that that isn’t the case here, so it’s probably more relevant to add additional checks or alter your `Rakefile` to not do anything if there’s nothing to do. Or you could rewrite your processing in a Makefile instead.)

I imagine you’ve already thought of this, but I think the ideal solution would be to add a new keyboard type instead of changing existing keyboard definitions; but there could well be some issue with this that I haven’t thought of.

Comment: Genius, thank you Stephen! (Yes, the Rakefile doesn't work like a Makefile and I don't much feel like rewriting it into a Makefile, either. It does do some checks of its own though and it won't be a problem to adapt it to work in the way you describe.)